# ContractsNotFound: Input JSON does not contain any sources

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, web3py

I'm trying to run this in the VS Code terminal for a Solidity Tutorial. Is there an error with my code, or could this be an issue with my environment?

Code:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

    # Compile Our Solidity
    install_solc("0.6.0")
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
        {
            "language": "solidity",
            "source": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
            "settings": {
                "ouputSelection": {
                    "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
                }
            },
        },
        solc_version="0.6.0",
    )
print(compiled_sol)
```

Error:

```
  File "/Users/eddiebraddock/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/deploy.py", line 8, in <module>
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/solcx/main.py", line 365, in compile_standard
    raise ContractsNotFound(
solcx.exceptions.ContractsNotFound: Input JSON does not contain any sources
> command: ``
> return code: `None`
> stdout:
None
> stderr:
None
```

Answer (score 1):

> Input JSON does not contain any sources

That means `sources` property is not defined. Insead of "source" use sources:

```
 "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
```

Also, I am not sure if it will affect but language should be "Solidity" with capital letter

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
"sources"
```

The question missed the 's' at the end:

```
"source"
```